# Transferring apps to new phone

Tags: applications

Applications
I updated my phone from Samsung s4 to Samsung a8. I transferred all my info with smart switch. Some app's  appeared and the rest are "in progress". It has been several days now, why are the apps still in progress please help. Btw I do not have WiFi

Answer (score 0):

So I believe you used a USB cable with a USB/microUSB adapter ?

If so, you may want to check the quality of your cable and/or use a better one (USB cables are NOT "all the same" : some are excellent, some are utter sh*t).

Unfortunately, the only tool I know for that goal is the QooPow qualMeter : http://www.qoopow.com/. It's a physical tool (= not an app) and a bit pricey, but if you find yourself lost in your cables, it might be a good investment for the future (your friends may find it useful too. Why not pool some money to get one for the lot of you ?).

Answer (score -1):

Use [ApowerManager](http://apowersoft.com/phone-manager) , not only the applications but also videos, 
 photos,contacts, messages, notes, books can be traferred from one phone to PC. Then import the files to your new phones. It gives you free choice to pick out the files you want. 
[image]

Comment: A number of questions to fulfill here: 1. What is your connection to this software - do you have an affiliation with this company and its software? 2. Why do you link directly to the company download vs. the apk on Google Play? 3. Are the versions different, and in what aspects?

Comment: Apowersoft is mostly known for spamming this site, which really doesn't say much for the quality of their software.